# Requests - Multiple proxies python

Tags: python, python-requests, http-proxy

I want to use multiple `http` proxies. As per the documentation, I cannot find the way to pass multiple proxies.

Here is my code:-

```
proxies = {
    'http': [List of IPs]
}
r = requests.get('http://10.1.7.70:8000', proxies=proxies)
```

While running this code, I get the following error:-

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I use multiple proxies?

Comment: `proxies` argument must be a dictionary containing protocol in keys and proxy address in values. For what you need multiple proxies?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev I have a similar use case. One is my college proxy which I have to use for any connection and the other is my custom proxy which I have configured and want to route my requests through that. How to test 2 proxies in such scenarios ?

Answer (score 15):

If your goal is to select a proxy from your list to use with requests:

```
import random
import requests

proxies_list = [List of IPs]

proxies = {
    'http': random.choice(proxies_list)
}
r = requests.get('http://10.1.7.70:8000', proxies=proxies)
```

If you want to chain proxies, requests cannot do it, you need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Proxies aren't lists, they are dictionaries indeed:

```
proxy = {key1:value, key2:value2,....}
```

You need to iterate by each key:

```
for i in proxy:
   r = requests.get('http://10.1.7.70:8000', proxies=proxy[i])
```